# Azure pipeline: get zip from https and extract into .txt

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to make an azure pipeline that downloads a .zip from an NHTSA database, extracts it into an azure blob storage container, and then converts it into delimited/.txt

So far, i've only been able to do the extract part (sort of), but when I try to extract the .zip into a delimited text file, I get an error that 'if there's a binary source, the sink must be binary also'. Does anyone have any advice/guidance on how to do this? Thanks!

Right now, I have a data factory with a single 'copy data' element. The source is an http link to static.nhs.gov/ and the relative path is odi/ffdd/cmpl/FLAT_CMPL.zip. There's no authorization needed, and I've set the type as a binary file. It copies the data to a binary-type azure storage blob. Right now, that pipeline successfully runs, but i can't find the .zip anywhere. Not sure why, because it worked at some point. Either way, I've only tried a linked, second copy data element that takes the blob .zip as its source and a new delimited file as its sink, which is where I get the binary source/sink mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

> if there's a binary source, the sink must be binary also

**The error is default behavior in ADF if your source data set is binary the sink dataset should be of binary type.**

> get zip from https and extract into .txt

**You need to build the pipeline with two copy activities.**

1. **First copy activity**.

-- In first copy activity you need to copy zip file from HTTP data source to blob storage with the binary dataset.

2. **Second copy activity**

-- In the second copy activity convert .zip file to .txt in blob storage.

In second activity take source with `DelimitedText` dataset and add the zip file which you want to cover to a .txt format and set the appropriate Compression type eg. `.zip.`

**Source dataset setting:**
[image]

In sink add dataset with `DelimitedText` type and create a your desired .txt file.

**Sink dataset settings:**
[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please include information in text format--your post is currently of little use for anyone who cannot access `https://i.imgur.com`. At the very least, i.stack.imgur.com would allow users with stackoverflow and associated sites to see where they currently cannot.

Comment: @TylerH added text description of each step .